# Magento deactivate Payment method for Guest

Tags: magento

I tried to write a little extension in order to deactivate a payment method (called IsrInvoice) if the user is accessing the checkout as guest user.

**/app/etc/modules/Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment/>
            </depends>
        </Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Shiftmint/Disable_GuestInvoice/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <models>
        <Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
            <class>Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice_Model</class>
        </Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
    </models>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice/Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</frontend>

</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Shiftmint/Disable_GuestInvoice/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Shiftmint_Disable_GuestInvoice_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymentMethodIsActive($observer)
    {
        $instance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $observer->getResult();

        if ($instance->getCode() == "IsrInvoice") {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $result->isAvailable = false;
                $result->save();
            } else {
                $result->isAvailable = true;
                $result->save();
            }
            $observer->setResult($result);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what I do wrong, because it is not working! Is there a way to test what is loaded?

Many thanks for advice,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You don't  need to write the code to deactivate the guest checkout. its magento inbuilt functionality. for that you log in go to **System menu>Configuration>Checkout** button in the **Sales** section on the left>Checkout Options panel on the right. After you expand the Checkout Options panel you'll see a drop-down menu Allow Guest Checkout; just set it to No. Once you do that a drop-down menu will appear under it labeled Require Customer To Be Logged in To Checkout; set it to Yes and click on the Save Config button in the upper right corner.

Comment: The idea is not to disable the checkout for guests, it's to allow/disallow payment methods if you are guest!